# CSS, Responsive, Make floating boxes stack up

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to create a responsive layout where there are two columns, left and right.
On smaller screens the boxes on the left has to move in to certain positions. This works great with my code but the problem is that on large screens there is a gap on the right side between the boxes.

How can I solve it?

**The idea and the problem**

[image]

**JSFIDDLE**

When you look at the following jsfiddle, you see that it works for the small screen, but the problems dont move up on large screen. I know the way I do it is wrong but how can I get to this desired result with CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/7rnum9xk/

```
.main{
    width:65%;
    height:125px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
}
.small{
    width:35%;
    height:25px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 692px)   {
    .main, .small{
        width:100%;   
        float:none;
    }    
}
```

Comment: try looking into .clearfix

Comment: do the colored elements have fixed heights?

Comment: No, every element has a dynamic height. The large and the small boxes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this code  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7rnum9xk/10/)

```
.main{
    width:65%;
    height:125px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
   float:left; 
    display: inline-block;
}
.small{
    width:35%;
    height:25px;
    /* float:left; */
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 692px)   {
    .main, .small{
        width:100%;   
        float:none;
    }

}

/* colors */
.main{background:#d0d0d0;}
.orange{background:#ecbd00;}
.green{background:#6aec00;}
.blue{background:#00c8ec;}
.purple{background:#c300ec;}
.red{background:#e93a73;}
```

Comment: Wahoo! At first sight you seem to be the hero of the day!

Comment: this is nice, +1 just make shure the colored elements are always smaller than the grey ones : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/7rnum9xk/11/

Comment: Great, but it'd be nice if you could point out what you have changed to achieve the desired look.

Comment: @web-tiki is there anything that can be done if the colored elements are occasionally larger than the grey ones?

Comment: I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33553259/821780) and I was able to do something that "half works", [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shy56Lkd/), using two divs for the 2 columns would make things easier, but it is not much on an option. Interestingly, having gaps in the right column would not be a problem for me.

Comment: perhaps [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5dhagLny/1/). I have no idea what I am doing ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the structure of the html, you have put the main div after every to small divs. So its going to print that div first.

What i would suggest doing is change the html structure like this;

float the left column left and the right column right.

Then place around a div around

add media css so that at 800px (or whatever you require) you can `display none;` on `.hide800` this hides the div, then add a div around your current html but put an inline style of display none. Then at 800px (or whatever size you hide the first div) add css to `display: block !Important;`

This way it will work how you need it for full width browsers, but then when the screen is small enough to change the structure you can use your current code.

html;

```
<div class="hide800">
    <div class="left-col">
    <div class="main">
    </div>
    <div class="main">
    </div>
    <div class="main">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class-right-col">
    <div class="small orange">
    </div>
    <div class="small green">
    </div>
    <div class="small blue">
    </div>
    <div class="small purple">
    </div>
    <div class="small red">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show800" style="display:none;">
<div class="main">
</div>
<div class="small orange">
</div>
<div class="small green">
</div>

<div class="main">
</div>
<div class="small blue">
</div>
<div class="small purple">
</div>

<div class="main">
</div>
<div class="small red">
</div>
</div>
```

css;

```
.left-col {
float: left;
}
.right-col {
float: right;
}
@media screen and(max-width:800px){
.hide800 {
display: none;
}
.show800 {
display: block !Important;
}
}
```

If you need me to explain further let me know :)

Comment: But that means I have to generate every small element twice? One time for in the show800 and one time for the hide800 elements? (correct me if i'm wrong)

I was hoping to get a solution that doesnt require to generate double content.

Comment: I think duplicating content is not good either. I'm in similar situation. What about libraries like isotope?

Comment: Ok not a problem, Sorry i couldn't help more.