# What is the best way to create an asymmetrical two-column grid with dynamic content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I have dynamic content flowing into a two-column grid. Flex box is a nice solution, but it forces the rows to be the same height, creating some awkward white space when one has more content. Does anyone know of a lightweight solution that can achieve what is hopefully clearly communicated in the below image?

Code for my current solution:

```css
.grid-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  height:auto;
  height:700px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
.contained-cell{
  width:48.5%;
  padding:40px 20px;
```

[image]

Comment: this is what helped me(if you are using Bootstrap) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668233/bootstrap-grid-uneven-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the flex items are aligned in a row by default (`flex-direction: row`). And also by default, flex items will stretch to occupy the full available height of the container (`align-items: stretch`) – thus creating equal height columns.

You could use `align-items: flex-start` to make each flex item stretch only enough to contain its content. But then, as you've noted, this doesn't change the height of the row, and the result is lots of vertical white space between items.

The standard solution for this layout is [**jQuery Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which, as they write on their website, *works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort of like a mason fitting stones in a wall.* That's one option.

Keeping to CSS, however, another flexbox solution is changing the `flex-direction` from `row` to `column`. With this set-up, equal height rows don't apply, vertical whitespace isn't an issue, and each flex item can be its own height.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8rq0maL4/1/

Comment: I was hoping to avoid Masonry, but it's seeming more like that's the way to go, especially considering that I'd like to order in a Z-pattern (top-left --> top-right --> [down a row]-left --> etc). Thanks so much, Michael!